# upcast from List<subclass> to List<superclass> via List<?>

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard

I have a class A and a class B extends A

In another class C I have a field

```
private List<B> listB;
```

Now, for some unusual reason, I have to implement this method in C

```
public List<A> getList();
```

I tried to do so by forcing an upcast of listB field to List`<A>` via a List`<?>` cast:

```
public List<A> getList(){
    return (List<A>)(List<?>)listB;
}
```

Clients should do

```
List<A> list = getList();
for(A a:list){
    //do something with a
}
```

I did some test and it seems work correctly, but honestly I am not sure of the all possible implications.

Is this solution correct? And Is it the best solution?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: `Stream<A> getAStream() { return listB.stream().map(A.class::cast); }` for read-only list access, as it should.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, this isn't generally type-safe. The client *shouldn't* be able to do

```
List<A> list = getList();
```

because otherwise they could write

```
list.add(new C()); // Where C extends A
```

Then the original code which knows about the list as a `List<B>` will have problems when it tries to use it, assuming that every element is compatible with `B`.

You could either wrap the original list to make it read-only, effectively - or make `getList` return a `List<? extends A>`, which means that clients won't be able to add items to it anyway.

If the list implementation you're using is unmodifiable, then it won't actually cause problems - but I'd still personally avoid it where possible.

Comment: The latter solution seems best here.  If an interface specified that it returned `List<? extends A>` then the concrete class could actually refine that to `List<B>`.  Alternatively, C could have a type parameter `class C<T extends A>` with `List<T> getList()`.

Comment: By the way, wrapping it is as easy as `return Collections.<A>unmodifiableList(listB);` (I'm not sure whether the explicit type will be needed in your case).  The library was smartly built to make this easy on you.

Comment: Even if there wasn't the problem of the element types, allowing modification of an internal collection like this is probably not what you want. I think copying is probably better than wrapping as unmodifiable, so that when the real collection is modified client code still holding a reference is not broken.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this is that clients can, unwittingly, insert `A` objects in what is actually a list of more specific `B` objects only:

```
c.getList().add(new A());
```

This will cause all kinds of breakage when your code tries to take an object from the list assuming that it's a `B`, but it isn't.

If your only goal is to let the client iterate over the list, it is better to hand out an `Iterable<A>` instead:

```
public Iterable<A> getAs() { return this.theListOfAs; }
```

Through this `Iterable`, one can only inspect and remove elements, but not add them.

If you want to disable removal as well, wrap the `List`'s `Iterable` in your own implementation, throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` when `remove()` is called.